# Custom user role doesn't show up in admin

Tags: user-roles

I followed a tutorial on how to add a custom user role, and when I put this in functions.php:

```
$result = add_role( 'user1', __(
    'user1' ),
    array(  ) );
```

..the new user role is supposed to show up in admin, on the "add new user" section, in the "role" dropdown. But it doesn't. Is there something else required for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing else required, it (should) work just fine with the code you posted. I've given this a quick test to confirm it is working and it does. So I'm assuming there is another problem somewhere.

Comment: I tested a moment ago, and now it is there! It wasn't before - really. Very strange...  Well, maybe I'll delete this topic.

Comment: I ran across this issue and when I cleared all caches (the host's cache seemed to be the kicker), the role started showing up where it was supposed to.